# Type conversion error

Tags: c#

```
int age = txtAge.Text;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can't, int and string are two completely different types. However, the most simple solution is:

```
int age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```

More secure is:

```
int age;
Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age);
```

Comment: note that you should probably check the `bool` that is returned from `TryParse`, and IMO it is far more common to see `int` than `Int32` (up to you, though).

Comment: On the first one I can agree, on the second one (int vs. Int32) it depends on what the programming conventions within a company say. My companies conventions state: use int for declarations and explicit conversions and Int32 for static method calls.

But of course it's all subjective to policy :).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int age;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age);

if (result)
{
    // Parse succeeded and get the result in age
}
else
{
    // Parse failed
}
```

See [Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

> The TryParse method is like the Parse
>   method, except the TryParse method
>   does not throw an exception if the
>   conversion fails. It eliminates the
>   need to use exception handling to test
>   for a FormatException in the event
>   that s is invalid and cannot be
>   successfully parsed.